# expectation of a standard normal within the CDF

Tags: calculus, probability

I was wondering if there is a way to compute the following expectation analytically?

$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{cZ}\Phi\left(a+bZ\right)\right]
$

where $Z$ is  a standard normal random variable and $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Z\sim N\left(0,1\right)$ and $f$ is a 'neat' function then:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{cZ}f\left(Z\right)\right]=e^{\frac{1}{2}c^{2}}\mathbb{E}f\left(Z+c\right)$$

We start with:

$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{cZ}f\left(Z\right)\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{cz-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}f\left(z\right)dz$.

Applying $v=z-c$ and we find:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{cz-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}f\left(z\right)dz=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{cv-\frac{1}{2}\left(v+c\right)^{2}}f\left(v+c\right)dv=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}c^{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^{2}}f\left(v+c\right)dv=e^{-\frac{1}{2}c^{2}}\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(Z+c\right)\right]$

Next to that we have: $$\mathbb{E}\Phi\left(a+bZ\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}}\right)$$

$\mathbb{E}\Phi\left(a+bZ\right)$can be recognized as $P\left(V\leq a+bZ\right)$
where $Z,V\sim N\left(0,1\right)$ are independent.

So $\mathbb{E}\Phi\left(a+bZ\right)=P\left(W\leq a\right)$ where
$W=V-bZ$.

Here $W\sim N\left(0,1+b^{2}\right)$ so $W'=\frac{W}{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}}\sim N\left(0,1\right)$.

This leads to $\mathbb{E}\Phi\left(a+bZ\right)=P\left(W\leq a\right)=P\left(W'\leq\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}}\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}}\right)$.

Applying these facts we find:

> $$\mathbb{E}e^{cZ}\Phi\left(a+bZ\right)=e^{\frac{1}{2}c^{2}}\mathbb{E}\Phi\left(a+bc+bZ\right)=e^{\frac{1}{2}c^{2}}\Phi\left(\frac{a+bc}{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed analysis.

Comment: You are very welcome.